# Does this bundle related differential equation always have non-trivial solutions?

Tags: differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations, riemannian-geometry, vector-bundles

Let $M$ be a smooth connected $d$-dimensional manifold, $E$ a vector bundle over $M$ of rank $d$. Let $\sigma \in \Omega^{d-1}(M,E)$ be a **non-zero** $E$-valued form on $M$ (of degree $d-1$).

I am interested in the **subspace** $A_{\sigma}=\{ h \in C^{\infty}(M) \, | \, \sigma \wedge dh =0\}$.

($dh$ is a real valued one form, so $\sigma \wedge dh \in \Omega^{d}(M,E)$).

$A_{\sigma}$ always contain the constant functions, so $\dim A_{\sigma} \ge 1$. Is it true that $\dim A_{\sigma} > 1$? Can $\dim A_{\sigma}$ be finite? infinite?

Can we construct an "explicit" basis for $A_{\sigma}$ (or even one non-constant function in $A_{\sigma}$) in terms of $\sigma$?

---

One possible strategy is to consider the relaxed equation $$\sigma \wedge \omega=0, \omega \in \Omega^1(M), \tag{1}$$

look for closed solutions, and hope they might be exact (The topology of $M$ might enter the game, of course).

Actually, we should start by making sure there is no **"pointwise"** obstruction to equation $(1)$:

Let $p \in M$. Does there exist $\omega_p \in T_p^*M$ such that $\sigma_p \wedge \omega_p=0$?

(This is a fiberwise question, on the level of linear algebra).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Locally $\sigma$ is given by

$$ \sum_{i,j=1}^d (-1)^{i-1}\sigma_i^j dx^1 \wedge \cdots \wedge \widehat{dx^i} \wedge \cdots \wedge dx^d \otimes e_j,$$

where $\{e_1, \cdots, e_d\}$ is a local basis for $E$. So

$$dh \wedge \sigma = \sigma_i^j h_i dx^1 \cdots dx^d \otimes e_j $$

So $\sigma \wedge dh = 0$ would mean $ \sigma \cdot h = 0$ (think as matrix multiplications). So for a generic $\sigma$, $\sigma_i^j$ is invertible on a dense subset of $M$, so $dh=0$ on a dense subset and so $dh=0$ on $M$.

Thus for a generic $\sigma$, $A_\sigma$ is one dimensional.

Comment: Thanks! Your observation is very nice. I actually have a specific $E,\sigma$ which interest me, and I would like to check if my $\sigma$ is "generic" in the sense you have described: In my case, I have a more invariant (coordinate-independent) description of $\sigma$. Do you think we can pharse this genericity in invariant terms? (I would be happy to find just a phrasing of the stronger condition "$\sigma$ is 'invertbile' everywhere", so I might use it to check whether or not my $\sigma$ satisfies this.

Comment: (I am more than ready to provide the specific details of my case, but I think it might be more helpful to stay in a rather general setting for now). I would just add that in my case $E$ is equipped with a metric and a compatible connection, so finding sufficient conditions for "invertibility" of a form in terms of such creatures could be helpful. (My $\sigma$ has some special properties which are related to the metric structures).

Comment: I think I solved my problem, now. Thanks again:) If I will have more specific concerns, I will just open a new question. I am still curious whether the dimension can be greater than $1$, though.

Comment: @AsafShachar: The dimension can be infinity. Let's assume for simplicity you use metric and orientation to identify $\Lambda^{d-1}(T^{*}M)$ with $\Lambda^{1}(T^{*}M)$ so you have an element $\sigma \in \operatorname{Hom}(TM,E)$ and you ask what are the $h$'s so that $\sigma(\nabla h) = 0$. It might be that $\sigma$ has a constant dimensional kernel so that $\ker \sigma$ is a subbundle $F$ of $TM$ and then you ask what are the $h$'s so that $\nabla h \in F$ and if $\dim F > 0$ this is an underdetermined equation for $h$ which should have infinitely many solutions locally.